# Wildfly Loghandler - Filter does not work

Tags: logging, filter, wildfly

I want to filter out certain statements from the wildfly console handler.

---

All statements containing the following string should not be logged:
`"subject" : "abc"` whereas `abc`is variable and could also be empty.

---

I configured the handler as follows:

```
<console-handler name="CONSOLE">
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <filter-spec value="not(match(&quot;\&quot;subject\&quot; : \&quot;.*?\&quot;&quot;))"/>
    <formatter>
        <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
</console-handler>
```

Unfortunately it does not work and still prints out the statements.

---

Strange thing is that even this filter does not work (I used it just as a test) to filter out all statements that somewhere contain `INFO`:
`<filter-spec value="not(match(&quot;INFO&quot;))"/>`

---

Can someone spot the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found an answer myself.

It seems that the filters only get applied to the **actual message** of the logging statement, but not the complete statement.

By consequence you can of course only filter on the message contents.